# Como descrever o banco de dados de um chat com varias pessoas

Tags: mysql

Que é fácil fazer uma conversa entre 2 pessoas, isso eu sei, mas e ai alguém pode citar o exemplo de como fazer uma conversa em grupo? Com um número ilimitado de pessoas.

Conversa entre 2 pessoas:

```
TABELA MYSQL

|   De    |     Para      |   Mensagem   |


|  User1  |     User2     |     Olá      |
```

---

> Alguém tem uma ideia diferente para adicionar mais pessoas nessa conversa?

Comment: uma mensagem para todos os usuários poderia utilizar a coluna para como null por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ou assim:

```
Table:
| Channel |  who                   | message |
|  #uno   | [nick1, nick2, nick3]  |   Olá   |
```

---

Ou:

```
| sender | receiver                | message |
|  nick1 | [nick2, nick3, nick 4]  |   Olá   |
```

---

Ou ainda

```
| id | Channel | who                  |
|  0 | #uno    | [nick1, nick2, ... ] |
----------------------------------
| sender  | toChannel | message |
|  nick1  | 0         |   Olá   |
```

---

As possibilidades são, literalmente, infindas; O que tens de te preocupar é ter uma lista de receptores da mensagem, e loopar "enquanto não enviei para este, envia, caso contrário tira-o desta lista"

Comment: Gostei da terceira resposta, a vista é muito eficaz, obrigado! :)